# forEach not a function when index starts at anything but 0

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, foreach

When inside an object there isn't an index that starts with 0, it returns:

> TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

This is how the database looks:

[image: This is how the database looks.]

If I add an object with the index 0 to the database, like so (my formatting doesn't matter, this is just to illustrate the hierarchy):

```
0: {
  email: "testmail",
  uid: "testuid"
}
```

Suddenly the forEach function works and also retrieves the users with index 3 and 4. How can I make the forEach loop start at index 3 for example? Or is there a different method that I should be using instead? My code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(props.klasData.gebruikers !== undefined) {
      var data = props.klasData.gebruikers;
      data.forEach(function (user) {
        if(!emails.hasOwnProperty(user.email)) {
          addEmail(oldArray => [...oldArray, user.email]);
        }
        setPending(false)
      })
    }
  }, []);
```

**Edit**
props.klasData.gebruikers returns all keys within the "gebruikers" object with their children.

Comment: We have no way to know what `props.klasData.gebruikers` is from the code you shared. Please edit your question to contain the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (I recommend reading the link, as it contains a lot of information that increases the chances that someone can help).

Comment: `.forEach()` is an Array method. We don't know what your object actually contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data is being interpreted as an array by the Firebase SDK, since it starts with sequential numeric keys. If you print the value of your `gebruikers` snapshot, you'll see that it's:

```
[null, null, null, {email: "test", uid: "test"}, {email: "wouter@...", uid: "..."}]
```

These `null` values are added by the Firebase SDK to turn the keys into a proper array.

If you want to keep the Firebase SDK from converting the data into an array, prefix the keys with a non-numeric character. For example:

```
"key2": {email: "test", uid: "test"}, 
"key3": {email: "wouter@...", uid: "..."}
```

---

In general, it is more idiomatic to use the UID of the users as the keys in a collection of users. That way, you won't need to query for the UID, and you're automatically guaranteed that each user/UID can only be present in the collection one.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I tried using key2 and key3 as keys instead of numeric keys, but it still returns "TypeError: data.forEach is not a function". This is weird because, I am using a forEach with uid's in another function and that seems to work fine. I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: While there may be more problems with your code, the one I explained above is definitely a problem and one that will be solved by changing the data structure I showed. If you stll have problems, edit your question to include the code I asked for in my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944821/foreach-not-a-function-when-index-starts-at-anything-but-0/64944956?noredirect=1#comment114819845_64944821

Answer (score 0):

I changed the database like [you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wxx3.png), as Frank van Puffelen suggested. As Frank also predicted, the root of my problem was coming from the function I didn't post.

By transforming all the indexes of UIDs I was fetching from the database to sequential numeric keys, I managed to get the forEach function working. I did this using `users = Object.values(users).filter((el) => {return el != null})`. The full effect hook can be found below:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    var refCodes = firebase.database().ref("userdata/" + currentUser.uid + "/docentCodes").orderByKey();
    refCodes.once("value").then(function (snapshotCodes) {
      snapshotCodes.val().forEach(function (code) {
        var refCodeData = firebase.database().ref("klassencodes/" + code).orderByKey();
        refCodeData.once("value").then(function (snapshotCodeData) {
          var users = snapshotCodeData.val().gebruikers;
          users = Object.values(users).filter((el) => {return el != null})
          if(snapshotCodeData.val() !== null) {
            setUsercount(oldArray => [...oldArray, users.length]);
            setKlasData(oldArray => [...oldArray, snapshotCodeData.val()]);
            setUserdata(oldArray => [...oldArray, users]);
            addCode(oldArray => [...oldArray, code])
          }
          setPending(false);
        })
      })
    })
  }, []);
```

In the function where this useEffect is used, I added `const [userdata, setUserdata] = React.useState([]);` to acommodate this new information stripped down from indexes of UIDs to indexes made of numeric keys. This userdata is exported to another function, which has the effect hook as stated in the original question. I changed this up to be:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(props.userData !== undefined) {
      var data = props.userData;
      if(data !== undefined) {
        data.forEach(function (user) {
          if(!emails.hasOwnProperty(user.email)) {
            addEmail(oldArray => [...oldArray, user.email]);
            addUID(oldArray => [...oldArray, Object.keys(props.klasData.gebruikers)]);
          }
          setPending(false)
        })
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

### Summary

In retrospect, I should've gone with a seperate const for just the userdata (`snapshotCodeData.val().gebruikers`), seperate from the other data returned from the snapshot (`snapshotCodeData.val()`).

I hope this may help you. The golden line of code is `users = Object.values(users).filter((el) => {return el != null})`.